# Notation to express $(n^1+n^2+...+n^k)$.

Tags: functions, notation

What are some mathematical conventions for expressing $(n^1+n^2+...+n^k)$ in a simpler format?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Do you mean a simpler notation, or a closed formula for the result?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  You could write it as $\sum \limits_{j=1}^k n^j$

If $S = n^1+n^2+n^3+n^4 +\cdots +n^k$

then  $nS=n^2+n^3+n^4 +\cdots +n^k+n^{k+1}$

so by subtraction $(n-1)S= n^{k+1} -n^1$

and thus $S = \dfrac{n}{n-1}(n^k-1)$

Comment: what does j=1 mean?

Comment: @J.Doe This is the sum notation. j=1 means, that j starts to count at 1 and then counts up to k. For example: $\sum_{j=1}^3 n^j=n^1+n^2+n^3$. You might check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation

Comment: ah ok, like for(j=1; j<k; j++) in standard computer programming syntax

Answer (score 1):

There is a sum-notation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k n^i=n+n^2+\dotso +n^{k-1}+n^k$$

Also this is a geometric sum so there is an explicit formula for it given by:

$$\frac{n(n^k-1)}{n-1}$$